# StreamWriter not releasing lock on a file even when including within Using clause

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I using C#.Net code to copy a file containing xml data to a location which is on a linux server. Soon after i copy the file i call a third party (java app) web-service that tries to consume the file copied. The third party service first tries to rename the file and in the process is getting an issue -Java File.renameTo method returns false. This suggests that the file is still being used/open by some other process.

The stream write code is given below

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(filename)
{
    file.WriteLine(xml);
    file.Close();
}
// Code that calls the web service follows
```

The file that is copied may be huge in size (20-30 MB in some cases). Is there any way we can fully confirm that the file has been completely copied to the location and that no process is holding on to the file before i call the third party service. I am sure there not other process holding on other than the one copying the file.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the *only* piece of your code that might be inappropriately maintaining an open handle on the file? Because a disposed `StreamWriter` shouldn't still have a handle.

Comment: Could be a permissions issue rather than an in-use issue?

Comment: As a diagnostic, put in a Sleep(1000) before calling the WebService. There could be a delay in the FileSystem.

Comment: To confirm if it is releasing the lock, manually rename the file, you will get an error if the file is still locked

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform a

`file.Close();
file.Dispose();`

That works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try naming the file something else, such as giving it a different extension that the consumer will not read. After you close the file, change the filename to whatever it should be, allowing the java code to grab the file and do what it needs to do.

Comment: The posted code is synchronous and calls the Service _after_ closing the file.

Comment: In this case, I would guess at permissions.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding a explicit `file.Flush();` just before `file.Close();`

Comment: The `Close()` does an implied `Flush()` and is already redundant. The `using(){}` should be enough.